# :selected in Zepto.js

Tags: jquery, zepto

I'm getting errors when doing .find("option:selected") in Zepto.js.  Is ":selected" even supported in Zepto?  If not, is there an equivalent way to make that work, without reverting to jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From skimming through the docs, I don't think so. That said, you should be able to do:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");
console.log(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I keep forgetting about "regular" JavaScript.  =)

Answer (score 4):

Zepto's default modules doesn't support :selected since it's not CSS standard, but you can add the 'selector' Zepto module for that feature (see the [Zepto Github page](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto) for building the lib with optional modules).

Alternatively, there is this workaround mentioned in the Zepto issues: https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/503

```
// get OPTION elements for which `selected` property is true
$('option').not(function(){ return !this.selected })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `$('select').val();` That seems to work for me.

Answer (score -1):

`$("#YOURselectID").val();` should work fine.

Also `:selected` will not work fine *zeptoJS*

You can also try this to get the text of the selected item.

```
$("#YOURselectID option["+$("#YOURselectID").val()+"]").html();
```

should work fine.

the format is `$(ID option[value]).html();`

Answer (score -1):

```
$('option:checked')
```

in my project, i used the above for instead.

[demo](http://jsbin.com/diqisa/edit?html,js)